# host a WebApplication in Vmware with shared Internet Network with Host-Machine

Tags: vmware, web-hosting

- I have Windows 7 as a Host OS on my PC, It's Connected to the Internet.
- I have a Win-Server 2016 on my VMware workstation. Its my Web-Application's host.
- Win-Server is Connected to the internet through my host os (Win 7) using a NAT connection.

I want to host my webApplication in this VM (winServer 2016) which has a shared Internet connection.

My Win-Server Connection has this Local IP Address: 192.168.111.19
My Win7 has this Local IP Address: 192.168.111.1

Both of them are Connected to the Internet using (something like) this IP: 86.10.15.20

When I host my Application in Win7, it will works through my Internet IP (86.10.15.20)

But When I host, my Application on Win-Server (in VM), I doesn't work at all.

Actually I don't know what Scenario I must implement to achieve this goal. Please note, what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to update the NAT rule to point to the Win-Server VM IP address instead of you Win7 IP address. This is normally done at the router level.